# Angular MatOptGroup Autocomplete with nested JSON structure

Tags: angular, autocomplete

There are examples of MatOptGroup filtering with JSON structure but they're not nested. And that's why I'm hanging on this problem.

```html
 <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Database</mat-label>
     <mat-select [formControl]="databaseControl">
         <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
         <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of databaseGroups" [label]="group.name" [disabled]="group.disabled">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let children of group.children" [value]="children.name">
                 {{children.name}}
             </mat-option>
         </mat-optgroup>
     </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

At the moment it works like this. The structure is nested like this:

```js
 export interface Database {
   name: string;
 }

 export interface DatabaseGroup {
   disabled?: boolean;
   name: string;
   children: Database[];
 }
```

There is an example without nested structure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smg2xm?file=app/app.component.ts

I've tried something like this but this won't work because to filter don't know the value of each other:

```js
   private _filterGroups(value: string): string[] {
     const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

     this.options = this.databaseGroups.filter(function (database) {
       database.children.filter(function (sipp) {
         return sipp.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue);
       })
     });

     return this.options;
   }
```

The solution without nested structure:

```js
filterGroup(val: string): SpeciesGroup[] {
 if (val) {
   return this.speciesGroup
     .map(group => ({ letter: group.letter, name: this._filter(group.name, val) }))
     .filter(group => group.name.length > 0);
 }

 return this.speciesGroup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```js
 export const _filterChildren = (opt: Database[], value: string): Database[] => {
   const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

   return opt.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
 };

   filteredOptions: Observable<DatabaseGroup[]>;
   databaseControl = new FormControl();
   databaseGroups: DatabaseGroup[];

   private _filterGroup(value: string): DatabaseGroup[] {
     if (value) {
       return this.databaseGroups
         .map(group => ({ children: _filterChildren(group.children, value), name: group.name }))
         .filter(group => group.children.length > 0);
     }

     return this.databaseGroups;
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.filteredOptions = this.databaseControl.valueChanges
       .pipe(
         startWith(''),
         map(value => this._filterGroup(value))
       );
   }
```

```html
 <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>{{'CSV.DBATTR' | translate}}</mat-label>
     <input matInput placeholder="{{'CSV.CHOOSE' | translate}}" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
         [formControl]="databaseControl">
     <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
         <mat-option>{{'CSV.NONE' | translate}}</mat-option>
         <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of filteredOptions | async" [label]="group.name">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let children of group.children" [value]="children.name">
                 {{children.name}}
             </mat-option>
         </mat-optgroup>
     </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

The two used interfaces you can find in the question and you can now autocomplete the children but just the children. If somebody has an idea how to autocomplete the parents or opt-groups as well feel free to answer.